# Product SlideShow in BootStrap 4

Tags: bootstrap-4

I Want to Show Product in SlideShow as Listbox,I'm Using this Link https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/4n1yK
But When I Want Change bootstrap version in 4.0.0 The page breaks down,How I Can Change version without problem?I'm New in Bootstrap And Want to learn

Answer (score 0):

All relevant changes and Information regarding upgrading bootstrap3 to bootstrap4 can be found in the official documentation: http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/migration/.

Looking at your code youll have to rewrite your whole grid system implementation as right now it doesnt follow one of the most important rules (see https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/):

> In a grid layout, content must be placed within columns and only
>   columns may be immediate children of rows

That will most likely break the whole thing when upgrading to bootstrap4 as the bootstrap grid is now using flexbox which wont work at all if you dont put your cols as immediate childs of your rows.